# C# Wpf Opacity Not Returning To 0

Tags: c#, wpf

so im attempting to make a simple function to fade in and out a UIElement
the issue that is occuring is the element fades in fine and has an opacity of 1 but on the fade out the opacity finishes at arround 0.01 oppose to 0.

```
        public static async Task<bool> FadeIO(UIElement target, int FadeTime = 100, int DelayBeforeFade = 5000, int DelayBeforeOutFade = 10000)
    {
        double OpacTick = 0; //The "counter" for the while loops.
        double FadeAmount = ((double)1 / FadeTime); //Calculates the required opacity increment for the fade to happen in the specified time.
        await Task.Delay(DelayBeforeFade); //Holds until the required delay before the fade has been reached.
        do
        {
            target.Opacity = 0 + OpacTick; //Alters the target's opacity based on the current loop cylce.
            OpacTick += FadeAmount; //Alters the counter by the pre calculated alteration amount.
            await Task.Delay(1); //Halts the loop

        } while (OpacTick <= 1); //Loops finished when the target's opacity is 1.
        OpacTick = 0; //Resets the loop counter.
        await Task.Delay(DelayBeforeOutFade); //Holds until the required delay before the fade out has been reached
        do
        {
            target.Opacity = 1 - OpacTick; //Alters the target's opacity based on the current loop cylce.
            OpacTick += FadeAmount; //Alters the counter by the pre calculated alteration amount.
            await Task.Delay(1); //Halts the loop

        } while (OpacTick <= 1); //Loops finished when the target's opacity is 0 and the counter is therefor 1.
        return true;
    }
```

The strangest thing about the issue is that when tested on different systems the opacity can fully return to 0 while on some systems it end at arround 0.01

Comment: Maybe you should set target.Opacity after updating OpacTick. But - why don't you use DoubleAnimation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last loop iteration doesn't get you to 0:

You set the opacity to ~0.01, *then* increment `OpacTick`, which is then checked against 1. It never actually sets the opacity to the incremented amount.

That being said, this is **totally** unnecessary. A `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` would serve you far better.